# How do I find full form of sgesv in LAPACK

Tags: objective-c, c, lapack

What is full form of sgesv?

I tried to go through the document [url](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/de8/sgesv_8f.html) , where I found parameter description but understanding this library without a meaning of the name is bit difficult.

Any pointer's to help understand this , would be helpful.

Comment: Be aware LAPACK was written in FORTRAN, and you are linking to the FORTRAN implementation and doxygen. CLAPACK is the C "port"; You may find it here – http://www.netlib.org/clapack/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming of routines in LAPACK sticks to the form `XYYZZZ`, where `X` indicates data type, `YY` indicates type of the most significant matrix, and `ZZZ` indicates the type of computation performed. In the case of `sgesv`,

- `X == s` stands for `REAL` data type.
- `YY == ge` stands for "general" matrix type.
- `ZZZ == sv` stands for linear system of equations.

See e.g. [this](http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/PAPERS/CRC-LAPACK-2005.pdf) document for more details.

Comment: Thanks, finally I will understand LAPACK.

Comment: @andyPaul For what it's worth, the complete set of data types goes as follows: `S` = single-precision floating-point. `D` = double-precision floating-point. `C` = single-precision complex floating-point. `Z` = double-precision complex floating-point. There are too many matrix types for me to recall, but the ones that have the form `hx` with x being some other character are usually Hermitian matrices of some kind.